# Django Redirects not working as Expected

Tags: python, django, message

I renamed this question as after diving deeper I discovered that is the root issue that was causing the messages to not display.

I am trying to redirect to a action status page to display a warning/success banner when a particular Django view returns a message to inform the user, I am not using forms.

Below is all code I have previously seen asked for, please let me know if you need more!

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'serversignup.apps.ServersignupConfig',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]

TEMPLATES = [
     {
         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
         'DIRS': [],
         'APP_DIRS': True,
         'OPTIONS': {
             'context_processors': [
                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
             ],
         },
     },
]
```

**message.html**

```
{%extends 'serversignup/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-12 main-content">
    {% if messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <strong>Action Failed: </strong> {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Update**
I created a test that works, and mirrored the code from the test, however it does not work. Test below.

**views.py**

```
def test(request):
    messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Success in signing out')
    return redirect('/messageAlert')


def update_signout_status(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        ...
        ...
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'This machine has already been claimed.')
    return redirect('/mesageAlert')


def message_alert(request):
    return render(request, 'serversignup/message.html', {})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/$', views.test, name='test'),
    url(r'^messageAlert/$', views.message_alert, name='alerts'),
    url(r'^updateSignoutStatus/$', views.update_signout_status, name='update_signout_status'),
]
```

Google Chrome network inspector shows the following:

**Scenario #1:** POST Request goes to 'updateSignoutStatus/'

```
Request URL:http://x.x.x.x/updateSignoutStatus/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
...
Request URL:http://x.x.x.x/messageAlert
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)
...
Request URL:http://x.x.x.x/messageAlert/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

**Behavior**

Page does not change to the redirected page.

```
[17/May/2017 09:30:32] "POST /updateSignoutStatus/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/May/2017 09:30:32] "GET /messageAlert/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1454
```

**Scenario #2:** GET Request goes to 'test/'

```
Request URL:http://x.x.x.x/test/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
...
Request URL:http://x.x.x.x/messageAlert
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
...
Request URL:http://x.x.x.x/messageAlert/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

**Behavior**

Page DOES change to the redirected page.

```
[17/May/2017 09:23:25] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[17/May/2017 09:23:26] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/May/2017 09:23:26] "GET /messageAlert HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[17/May/2017 09:23:26] "GET /messageAlert/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1446
```

**Edit #1:** Modified code to reflect current state after receiving insight on how messages work, issue still persists.

**Edit #2:** Added more context to index.html & views.py code.

**Edit #3:** Update on issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this occurred, but the issue seems to be resolved. The changes I made were the following:

Previously I was using javascript to form the POST request that would start the chain leading to the redirect message.

I have since switched over to using an HTML form to do the POST and the behavior now works. I believe the issue has something to do with the datatype that was being sent via Javascript and was generating the xhr message in response.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the messages has the effect of clearing them. By having that for loop in your view, you cause them to be deleted before the template is rendered.

Remove that loop.

Comment: I have removed the loop and it still does not display, thanks for the advice though, I did not know this.

Answer (score 0):

Messages will clear once it processed. So to avoid that

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
for message in storage:
    print(message)
storage.used = False
```

Comment: Thanks! Someone else asked me to remove the loop which I ended up doing, unfortunately the issue still persists even without the loop.

Comment: Ok. what is there in context? Then If you can post your full index.html, please post it on question

Comment: Try this `MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'` in settings.py

Comment: I added this to the settings.py file with no luck, I appreciate the continued assistance.

Comment: Can you check html content using page source whether message is there or not? may be a chance that div is under your table

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was able to check to page source in browser, I can see the page refresh but cannot find the div that should be present.

Answer (score 0):

Check `COOKIE_SESSION_DOMAIN` setting. I had a problem once with missing messages due to this setting using a different domain name than the site where the code is actually run. So Django couldn't read messages from session.

Comment: As I develop the site I am accessing it based on http://<IP_Address>/location and not an actual Domain Name URL, could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes, if you have `COOKIE_SESSION_DOMAIN` set to some domain. Just open Django shell and run: `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.COOKIE_SESSION_DOMAIN)`